# System.TypeLoadException when using CrmSvcUtil.exe to generate OrganizationServiceContext

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm having an issue with my plugin. I used to generate early bound classes by using CrmSvcUtil.exe. I also generated my own OrganizationServiceContext by typing organizationservicename attribute to commad line when running crmsvcutil.exe.

But now when I'm creating LINQ queries by using my own OrganizationServiceContext I'm getting following error:

System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceRegistrationFailedException.GetObjectData
(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)' Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.

So has any of you any experience what could this mean? It's probably something to do with that I'm generating my own OrganizationServiceContext?

I tried to use default OrganizationServiceContext but for some reason then I can't access any entity sets (for example AccountSet) which I'm going to use to create some LINQ queries.

If you need some code samples please ask.

EDIT: SOLUTION:

Okey, I managed to solve this one. I didn't have reference to Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query and Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq

But as we don't want to leave this post right here someone could give me very brief explanation why I was still able to build that project after all and didn't receive any error.

Comment: So your plugin dll includes your `OrganizationServiceContext` and your entities?